# CSS transition, position keeps moving on hover

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I have a simple css transition on the `right` property for a button which simply moves an arrow when you hover. The problem is that when you hover, it's not transitioning properly and if you refresh (or re-run) the JSFiddle, then you will notice that the arrow moves position after hovering.

It's like it moves back, then forwards then back again?

This appears to only happen in Firefox.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhz9dg0n/)

Comment: you wanted to kepp the arrow moving infinitely on hover?

Comment: When you hover, it should move right, but instead it's moving left and then right. Then if you refresh/re-run it repositions the arrow.

Comment: Looks fine for me. Chrome 50 on OSX

Comment: Looks like a Firefox issue!

Comment: I haven't seen that arrow has repositioned. The arrows original position is at the left so when you did `mouseover` or `mouseout` on it, it'll move oppositely.

Comment: Tried in MS Edge and Chrome. Works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine on all latest browsers. What browser are You using?

Comment: It appears that the position that the arrow uses for 'hover' is rendering as the start position (in Firefox). When you mouse over the button, it suddenly recognises that the start position is different, so it plays the animation from there. That's why you see the 'jump'. I'll do some fiddling but it may be a FF bug.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look guys. It's strange but removing the <span> tag and applying this directly on the button seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/dhz9dg0n/2/

Comment: You can reproduce it even by checking off the `right: -25px;` value from the firebug (or dev inspector tool) and checking it on again. Really strange...

Comment: **It's not a firefox bug**, it's the **correct behaviour for inline elements** (`<span>` element in this case). Turn the span to inline-block and it works (or remove the span that's unneccesary).

Comment: Develop in Chrome causes that all correct behaviours to think that's a bug because in chrome doesn't happens. Chrome is the buggiest browser right now. The new IE6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the problem. Your span is inline, and giving it `position: relative` caused the issue.

Simply change to `inline-block` and you're good to go:

```
.genericBtn span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd say. My upvote to you. Another solution is remove the span, that's unnecesary

Comment: You got in with the answer 8 seconds before me, so removing my reply ;)

Comment: @AaronLavers Happens to me all the time! :D

Comment: Didn't know this.. TIL Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Narxx! The only reason I added the span is so I can position the arrow relative to the text instead of the entire button.

Answer (score 5):

How about using a more subtle approach by using CSS pseudo elements:

```
.genericBtn {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #c40009;
  border: 1px solid #c40009;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 30px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;}

.genericBtn::after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  right: 37%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.genericBtn:hover::after {
  transform: translate(10px,0); }
```

---

### Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgt50ef7/2/)